# When I click on "Ask Question" I get diverted to my last question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Is it me? something I am doing wrong?
When I click on Ask question I get diverted the page of editing my last question

[image]

Comment: Could be a caching issue? Have you tried doing a force-refresh (ctrl-F5/shift-F5 depending on browser)?

Comment: @CMaster yes, also I am using work computer now, still same problem?!

Comment: That's a feature: your last edited questions is cached in case you want to keep editing it later.

Comment: @JonathanReez I am aware of the feature but I want to ask a new question, it's stuck

Comment: You mean you can't remove that text?

Comment: @JonathanReez I can but I dont want to kill the question and even if it does not kill the existing question I dont want to do that every time I ask a question! since when they updated this feature? I have tried other SE sites and there is no such thing

Answer (score 8):

What you are seeing is a *draft* - you have not asked the question, but are shown the saved draft.

You can *discard* the draft by clicking the "discard" link on the page (next to the "Post your question" button).

We do not support multiple drafts.

Answer (score -4):

Log out of the site then log in again, that will solve the problem.